# Cannot set property of undefined setting при глубоком копировании

Tags: javascript

Попробовал реализовать функцию глубокого клонирования объекта:

```js
function deepCloning(src, dst) {
  for (let key in src) {
    if (typeof src[key] == 'object') {
      deepCloning(src[key], dst[key]);
    } else {
      dst[key] = src[key];
    }
  }
}

let bag = {
  ["Yes or no?"]: "yes",
  "sort": "red",
  "count": 5,
  pocket: {
    height: 50,
    width: 100
  }
};
let clone = {}
deepCloning(bag, clone);
```

На свойстве height вылезает выше упомянутая ошибка. Почему она появляется именно в данном случае и можно ли её устранить, используя нативный js и не сильно увеличивая код в размере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(typeof src[key] == 'object') {
        deepCloning(src[key], dst[key] = {});
                                      ^^^^^
    } else {
```

```js
function deepCloning(src, dst) {
  for (let key in src) {
    if (typeof src[key] == 'object') {
      deepCloning(src[key], dst[key] = {});
    } else {
      dst[key] = src[key];
    }
  }
}

let bag = {
  ["Yes or no?"]: "yes",
  "sort": "red",
  "count": 5,
  pocket: {
    height: 50,
    width: 100
  }
};
let clone = {};
deepCloning(bag, clone);
console.log(clone);
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибка исчезла, но в таком случае он не проходит по вложенному объекту.

Comment: @Enesan Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.